# Create buttons for work book from instruction sheet on the workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry That I posted my whole code for better visual. I created getcol function to give it the string( column name ) and it returns the range of that column

```
Public Function getColRange(colName As String) As String

    'create variables that will be used in this function
    Dim first As String
    Dim last As String
    Dim col As String
    Dim first_row As Integer
    Dim first_str As String
    Dim last_col As String
    Dim last_row As Integer
    Dim last_str As String
     
    'loop to check if colname is equal in range between columns A and X, easy to change below
    For Each i In Range("A1:X1")
        If i = colName Then
            'catches column, first and last rows
            col = Split(i.Address(1, 0), "$")(0)
            last_row = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
            first_row = 2
            
            'make first and last addresses as strings
            first_str = "" & col & first_row
            last_str = "" & first_col & last_row
            
            'function ouput in the next line is a combination of above two strings
            getColRange = "" & first_str & ":" & col & last_str
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Option Explicit
Sub proper_text()
Dim name_rng As Range
Dim name_cell As Range
Dim name_selection As String
Dim city_rng As Range
Dim city_cell As Range
Dim city_selection As String

```
    Dim col_name As String
    Dim trim_name_row As Long
    Dim trim_name_rng As Range
    Dim trim_name_cell As Range
    Dim col_city As String
    Dim trim_city_row As Long
    Dim trim_city_rng As Range
    Dim trim_city_cell As Range
    
    With Credentialing_Work_History
        ' First Part
        name_selection = getColRange("Company_Name")
        Set name_rng = Range(name_selection)
        For Each name_cell In name_rng
            name_cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(name_cell.Value)
        Next
        
        city_selection = getColRange("Company_City")
        Set city_rng = Range(city_selection)
        For Each city_cell In city_rng
            city_cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(city_cell.Value)
        Next
        'Second Part
        col_name = getColRange("Company_Name")
        ' To 'Find the last used cell in Col A
        trim_name_row = Range(col_name).End(xlDown).Row
        
        'Declare the range used by having the coordinates of rows and column till the last cell used.
        Set trim_name_rng = Range(Cells(2, 9), Cells(trim_name_row, 9))
        ' Loop through the range and remove any trailing space
        For Each trim_name_cell In trim_name_rng
            trim_name_cell = RTrim(trim_name_cell)
        'Go to the next Cell
        Next trim_name_cell
        
        col_city = getColRange("Company_Name")
        trim_city_row = Range(col_city).End(xlDown).Row
        
        Set trim_city_rng = Range(Cells(2, 10), Cells(trim_city_row, 10))
        
        For Each trim_city_cell In trim_city_rng
            trim_city_cell = RTrim(trim_city_cell)
        Next trim_city_cell
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Side notes: use `Long` instead of `Integer`, add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module, and declare all variables.

Comment: As I told you in my answer, you have to put a dot (`.`) in front of every range and cells (in your case) i.e. `.Range(whatever)` and `.Cells(whatever)`. And use the function I posted which is only slightly corrected but working. Then you will also have to correct the selection lines e.g. `getColRange(Credentialing_Work_History, "Company_Name")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Referring to the Same Worksheet

- Always use `Option Explicit`. If you would have used it, you would have noticed that the variables `city_selection` and `city_cell`, and `i` are not declared.
- When having a 'ton' of variables, keep them close to the 'action' to make the code more readable (see in `Quick Fix`). Use shorter variable names, always preferably (but not necessarily) descriptive.
- When using the `With` statement, you have to use the period (dot, `.`) in front of `Worksheets`, `Range`, `Cells`, `Columns`, `Rows`...etc., e.g.:

  ```
  With Credentialing_Work_History
      Set name_rng = .Range(name_selection)
  End With
  ```

  In this example, you have made sure that the range is in the worksheet `Credentialing_Work_History`.
- You don't have to loop through the cells of the range, you can use `Proper` and `Trim` on a range (if you will allow `Trim` instead of `RTrim`).
- You have to qualify your ranges i.e. make sure they refer to the correct worksheet. See this also in the corrections of the function (added `ws` parameter).
- Note that the function would be more useful if it would return a range instead of a range address so you could use e.g. `Set name_rng = getColRange(Credentialing_Work_History, "Company_Name")`. That could be one of your next tasks.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub proper_text()
        
    ' Name
    Dim name_selection As String
    Dim name_rng As Range
    name_selection = getColRange(Credentialing_Work_History, "Company_Name")
    If name_selection <> "" Then
        Set name_rng = Credentialing_Work_History.Range(name_selection)
        name_rng.Value = Application.Trim(Application.Proper(name_rng.Value))
    End If
    
    ' City
    Dim city_rng As Range
    Dim city_selection As String
    city_selection = getColRange(Credentialing_Work_History, "Company_City")
    If name_selection <> "" Then
        Set city_rng = Credentialing_Work_History.Range(city_selection)
        city_rng.Value = Application.Trim(Application.Proper(city_rng.Value))
    End If
 
End Sub

Function getColRange(ws As Worksheet, colName As String) As String

    'create variables that will be used in this function
    Dim first As String
    Dim last As String
    Dim col As String
    Dim first_col As String
    Dim first_row As Long
    Dim first_str As String
    Dim last_col As String
    Dim last_row As Long
    Dim last_str As String
    Dim rg As Range
     
    'loop to check if colname is equal in range between columns A and X, easy to change below
    For Each rg In ws.Range("A1:X1")
        If rg = colName Then
            'catches column, first and last rows
            col = Split(rg.Address(1, 0), "$")(0)
            last_row = ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
            first_row = 2
            
            'make first and last addresses as strings
            first_str = "" & col & first_row
            last_str = "" & first_col & last_row
            
            'function ouput in the next line is a combination of above two strings
            getColRange = "" & first_str & ":" & col & last_str
        End If
    Next rg

End Function

Sub proper_text_QuickFix()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Credentialing_Work_History
        
    ' Name
    Dim name_selection As String
    Dim name_rng As Range
    Dim name_cell As Range
    name_selection = getColRange(ws, "Company_Name")
    Set name_rng = ws.Range(name_selection)
    Debug.Print name_rng.Address
    For Each name_cell In name_rng
        name_cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(name_cell.Value)
    Next
    
    ' City
    Dim city_name_selection As String
    Dim city_rng As Range
    Dim city_name_cell As Range
    city_name_selection = getColRange(ws, "Company_City")
    Set city_rng = ws.Range(city_name_selection)
    Debug.Print city_rng.Address
    For Each city_name_cell In city_rng
        city_name_cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(city_name_cell.Value)
    Next
    
    ' Trim Name
    Dim col_name As String
    Dim trim_name_row As Integer
    Dim trim_name_rng As Range
    Dim trim_name_cell As Range
    
    col_name = getColRange(ws, "Company_Name")
    trim_name_row = ws.Range(col_name).End(xlDown).Row
    Set trim_name_rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 9), ws.Cells(trim_name_row, 9))
    Debug.Print name_rng.Address
    For Each trim_name_cell In trim_name_rng
        trim_name_cell = RTrim(trim_name_cell)
    Next trim_name_cell
    
    ' Trim City
    Dim col_city As String
    Dim trim_city_row As Integer
    Dim trim_city_rng As Range
    Dim trim_city_cell As Range
    
    col_city = getColRange(ws, "Company_City")
    trim_city_row = ws.Range(col_city).End(xlDown).Row
    Set trim_city_rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 10), ws.Cells(trim_city_row, 10))
    Debug.Print trim_city_rng.Address
    For Each trim_city_cell In trim_city_rng
        trim_city_cell = RTrim(trim_city_cell)
    Next trim_city_cell
 
End Sub
```

Comment: When I am on Credentialing_Work_History tab the code is working fine like my original code I posted. Same problem because once I go instruction sheet and press on macro button I created there, it gives me(" Run time error '1004' ,Method 'Range' of object'_Global Failed") . Why its working only when I am on the sheet that macro runs on and not from button I created on another sheet.

Comment: Generally good and helpful advise, but contains a few subjective points that can be situation-specific, rather than absolute. These are (1) ALWAYS use Option Explicit [better: use it unless you know exactly why you aren't], (2) Keep declarations close to the action, (3) Keep variable names short and not descriptive. All 3 of these are "horses for courses" and work well in this situation but not in all other situations.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. When you put it like that, I'll have to agree with some of it. Fixed it a little bit. Cannot agree on the `Option Explicit` part though.